# jQuery not function dependency on the value of another control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(serialNumbersDDL).children("option:gt(0)").remove();
```

It will delete all the options except the first one. Now I need to delete all the options except the first one and also not delete the option whose value is equal to the label text. How can I say that with writing limited amount of code?

Comment: maybe you can do it in 2 line if that is not too much code for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$("option:not(':first')",serialNumbersDDL).filter(function(){
return $(this).val()!=$(this).text();
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try

```
$(serialNumbersDDL).children("option:gt(0)").not(function(){
    return $(this.labels).text() == this.value;
}).remove();
```